# NodeJS custom Middleware display calling parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, routes

Objective:  Display the parent function of a middleware function

```
shared              = require('./RoutFuctions');

app.post('/link', shared.verifyToken, (req, res) => {
...
}
```

> Inside  function

```
exports.verifyToken = function(req, res, next) {
   console.log('this function was called by ' + ?parentFunction? )
   ...
   next()
}
```

Is there something I can put in place of ***?parentFunction?*** (__filename is not specific enough)
OR is there way to pass a in an optional parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by passing in parameter one node back on clients side.

```
  return axios
    .post('/link', {
      token: token,
      caller: 'myParentFunction'
    })
...
```

then inside verifyToken the **caller** variable can be access using ***req.body.caller***

```
exports.verifyToken = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('verifyToken caller = ' + req.body.caller)
   ...
   next()
}
```